# RCA Socket Pinout

Tags: pinout

I have been longing online for quite a well for the pinout of an RCA socket, but I can't seem to find the exact pinout.  It only has two pins, a center one, and one right in front of the center pin.  Looks like [this](http://rarecomponents.com/store/image/cache/data/RCA_Jack_RED_2-500x500.jpg), one website said that one of the pins is ground, which left me sort of confused.  What is the exact pinout of the this component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image] [image]

*Figure 1. The near pin is obviously connected to the outer ring of the socket. This forms a shield for the signal pin going through the centre to the pin at the rear of the socket. Figure 2. The plug showing the signal pin (centre) and the shield / ground (outer).*

Connect ground to the shield pin (the near one in the photo).

Comment: So the center pin is a female connection part?

Comment: Yes, although the shell of the plug (Figure 2) covers the shell of the socket (Figure 1) so the plug goes into the socket which fits into the plug!